# StackOverflow error when update a Observable List using Flutter with GetX

Tags: flutter, list, observable, stack-overflow, flutter-getx

I'm creating a screen where the user can answer multiple questions. These questions are called "protocols," so they can answer about their sleep time and pain.
I fetch a list of protocols from a Rest API, and when the user answers a protocol, I update that protocol in the received API list.
However, in doing so, I'm encountering a "StackOverflow error."

GetxController:

```
  @override
  onInit() async {
    await fetchProtocol();
    tabController = TabController(length: protocols.length, vsync: this);
    loading.value = false;
    super.onInit();
  }

  Future<void> fetchProtocol() async {
    try {
      protocols.value = await repository.fetchProtocol(protocolId!);
    } catch (e) {
      showErrorDialog(
          dimissible: false,
          onClicked: () =>
              Get.offAllNamed(Routes.training, arguments: trainignId),
          message: "Parece que você não pode responder a este protocolo.");
    }
  }
  updateProtocol(Protocol newProtocol) {
    protocols.value = replaceProtocolById(protocols, newProtocol);
  }
```

View:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => true,
        child: Scaffold(
            bottomNavigationBar: const SizedBox.shrink(),
  appBar: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
              child: AppBar(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                      bottom: const Radius.circular(5).r,
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: Text(controller.title ?? "",
                      maxLines: 1,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 22.sp,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                  centerTitle: true,
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  leading: null),
            ),
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Container(
                  width: Get.width,
                  height: Get.height,
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 342.w,
                    child: Obx(() {
                      if (controller.loading.value) {
                        return Loading();
                      } else {
                        return TabBarView(
                            controller: controller.tabController,
                            children: List.generate(controller.protocols.length,
                                (index) {
                              if (controller.protocols[index].id == 4) {
                                return PainProtocol(
                                  onFeel: controller.changeViewedProtocol,
                                  onNotFeel: controller.changeViewedProtocol,
                                  position: controller.position.value,
                                  show: controller.viewedProtocol.value,
                                  onConfirmPains: controller.updateProtocol,
                                  protocol: controller.protocols.value[index],
                                );
                              } else {
                                return Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                      controller.protocols.value[index].name!),
                                );
                              }
                            }));
                      }
                    }),
                  )),
            )));
  }
```

Protocol class:

```
class Protocol {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? nickname;
  String? measure;
  int? order;
  Value? value;
  List<Indicator>? indicator;
  String? type;

  Protocol(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.nickname,
      this.measure,
      this.order,
      this.value,
      this.indicator,
      this.type});
```

Comment: yeah, im on the getx discord..

Comment: Randal, the project is still small and changing the state manager wouldn't be a problem. But if you can help me solve the issue above using GetX, I would be very happy.

Comment: what is inside `replaceProtocolById`?

Comment: List<Protocol> replaceProtocolById(
      List<Protocol> localProtocols, Protocol newProtocol) {
    for (var i = 0; i < localProtocols.length; i++) {
      if (localProtocols[i].id == newProtocol.id) {
        localProtocols[i] = newProtocol;
        break;
      }
    }

    return localProtocols;
  }

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. And no, the Getx is no the guilty of the error! I'v used some recursive funcitons to update the list, and, this cause the error. And a recomendation, use "value" into RxLists.